# Can i add extra parameters to an IBDataset

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to add extra params to an IBDataset.
I would like to add a couple of extra values to the insert sql for fields that don't exist in the select sql.

I don't think Delphi supports this, but i wondered if anyone had any unique workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the insert *manually*. For example if you have this selectSQL:

```
select somefield
  from sometable
```

You can write a OnUpdateRecord event handler and do it *manually* for the `ukInsert` kind of update, using a insert query like:

```
insert into sometable (somefield, someotherfield)
values (:somefield, :someotherfield)
```

After you applied the insert, you set the `uaApplied` value for the UpdateAction var parameter.